# LWC JS controller can not find a declared method

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

```js
 showToast() {
     const event = new ShowToastEvent({
         title: 'Get Help',
         message:
             'Salesforce documentation is available in the app. Click ? in the upper-right corner.',
     });
     this.dispatchEvent(event);
 }

 saveModal(){
     try {
         this.openModal = false;
         markImportant({Id: this.row.Id}).then(showToast());
     } catch (exception) {
         console.log(exception);
     }
 }
```

On `saveModal()` method I'm getting an exception:

> ReferenceError: showToast is not defined.

Could you point out my error, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `showToast()` is not defined within `saveModal` function scope, but defined within component scope. To access `showToast()` member function use `this`.
2. You can handle Promise errors using [`Promise.catch(e)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) method:

```js
saveModal(){
    this.openModal = false;
    markImportant({Id: this.row.Id})
       .then(() => this.showToast())
       .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```